# Issue installing HandBrake

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I am attempting to install handbrake by using the below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

Which throws an error of:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>   
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    handbrake-gtk : Depends: libmp3lame0 (>= 1:3.99.0) but 3.99.5+repack1-7+deb8u1 is to be installed
>                    Recommends: gstreamer1.0-x but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I ran thebelow to see what was held broken packages:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

Which returned nothing.  So I then decided to check on both gstreamer and libmp3lame0 and ran

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Which presented a message of * program is already installed.  Then again I tried

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

And the errors I got were:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>   
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    handbrake-gtk : Depends: libmp3lame0 (>= 1:3.99.0) but 3.99.5+repack1-7+deb8u1 is to be installed
>                    Recommends: gstreamer1.0-x but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Lastly, I tried using `sudo apt-get install -f handbrake-gtk` which threw the same error as installing with no `-f` parameter.

With all that being said, what do I need to do in order to install handbrake?

And my system details are:

> DistributerID: BunsenLabs
>   
> Description: BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 8.5 (Hydrogen)
>   
> Release: 8.5
>   
> Codename: Bunsen-Hydrogen

**EDIT**
I am looking for a video convertor (i.e. re-encoder to resize and change the container on some cell phone videos)

Comment: As far as I remember BunsenLabs was based directly on Debian and not Ubuntu and HandBrake's repo is for Ubuntu (yes Ubuntu is based on Debian and they are similar, but there are some differences as well) so this might not work at all.

Comment: @SledgeHammer - ah, thank you for that valuable insight.  Is there an alternative to handbrake that I can use for video conversion on this particular Debian install?

Comment: You can install it from Bunsen's repositories (I'm not sure but it might just be using Debian's). It won't be the latest version but it should work on your machine. First you have to remove the added repo with `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases` and then do the following: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install handbrake`

Comment: Posted as answer, I'm just not sure whether we should delete the comments or leave for the moderators to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bunsen Labs is based directly on Debian, so you shouldn't be able to install Handbrake from its official repository.

You can install it instead from Bunsen's repositories. It won't be the latest version but it should work on your machine.

First you have to remove the added repo with

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases`

and then do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```